# Python:Convert into JSON Format

Tags: json, python-3.x

**Requirement**: Convert plain text into JSON format

**Input:**

```
  data3 =   "{   'type': 'service_account',   'project_id': 'innate-paratext-90872'}"
```

**Expected Output in JSON format:**

```
{
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "innate-paratext-90872"
}
```

**Tried:**
**Method 1**

```py
json_str = json.dumps(data3)
```

**output**:

```
"{   'type': 'service_account',   'project_id': 'innate-paratext-90872'}"
```

**Method 2:**

```
json_str = json.loads(data3)
```

**Error**:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 5 (char 4)
```

> EDIT 1: Solution given by Mark Tolonen below works fine but it strips of some as an example below

```
data3 = "{'type': 'service_account',   'project_id': 'innate-paratext-90872',   'private_key': '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BA\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\\n'}",
```

**Expected Output:**

```
"private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BA\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
```

**Your Code output: (it has striped out "\" in the "\n")**

```
"private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAn-----END PRIVATE KEY-----n",
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string is in Python source format, so you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert it to a true Python dictionary suitable for `json.dumps`:

```
>>> s = "{   'type': 'service_account',   'project_id': 'innate-paratext-90872'}"
>>> import ast
>>> d = ast.literal_eval(s)
>>> d
{'type': 'service_account', 'project_id': 'innate-paratext-90872'}
>>> import json
>>> print(json.dumps(d,indent=4))
{
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "innate-paratext-90872"
}
```

Comment: I have updated the original question got another issue it has stripped some